# PHP file_get_contents returning bool(false)

Tags: php, json

I am trying to save the contents of an `XML` file into a `string` and then convert into `JSON`. However, the file I upload isn't being read by `file_get_contents` because it's returning `false`. I did read other posts on the same issue but their file paths were URLs. Does anyone know what's causing this error?

```
<?php


if(isset($_POST['xml_submit'])) {
//get the xml file
$file = file_get_contents($_FILES['upload_file']['tmp_name']);
$file_string = simplexml_load_string($file);
$json = json_encode($file_string);
$json_decoded = json_decode($json, true);
//Testing if file is being read in
var_dump($file_string);



}
?>

<!-- Upload file form -->
<form class="form-horizontal" method="post" name="upload_excel" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <fieldset>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="filebutton">Select File</label>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <input type="file" name="xml" id="xml" class="input-large" accept=".xml">
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <button type="submit" id="submit" name="xml_submit" style="color: #D96B27;border: 1px solid #D96B27" data-loading-text="Loading...">Submit</button>
            </div>
        </div>

    </fieldset>
</form>
```

Comment: feel free to add an xml file for testing..

Comment: `file_get_contents()` returns false on error, which has nothing to do with the contents of the file. Either the file doesn't exist, or you don't have permissions to read it.

Comment: your html name is "xml" not "upload_file"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must use `$_FILES['xml']['tmp_name']`.